# Merging CSV File Data Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, csv, scripting, command-prompt

I would like to merge the data of two CSV files with a batch script, if possible.

The issue is that although they contain similar data, it is not in order and needs to be amalgamated/merged. I would just like the last column of this file

```
Isher,Dhupar,7,7M5,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
Saarah,Hassan,7,7M5,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
Zenzele,Kabara-Clarke,7,7M5,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
```

to be added onto the next row of this file where it is the right person.

```
Abed,Abbas,P,J3XXXXXXXXXXX,7,NULL,abedabbas,****,A
Muzefa,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,8,NULL,muzefaabbas,****,A
Taiba,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,11,NULL,taibaabbas,****,A
```

i.e. it would make the following transition:

```
Abed,Abbas,P,J3XXXXXXXXXXX,7,NULL,abedabbas,****,A,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
Muzefa,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,8,NULL,muzefaabbas,****,A,8fj/Ma1   Mrs C H CLARK
Taiba,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,11,NULL,taibaabbas,****,A,11ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
```

I've managed to construct a batch file that reads the first two fields in the second CSV file and stores into an array, but that's all:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set n=0

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (Database.csv) do (
    set names[!n!]=%%a,%%b
    set /a n+=1
)
set /a n-=1

for /l %%f in (0,1,%n%) do (
    echo !names[%%f]!
)

endlocal
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wow! You should realize that the example data usually serve to *clarify* the question, so a reader may easily follow the problem description reviewing the example. However, in this case your example just *distract us* from the description, because there is not a single case of "right person" matching data on it! Anyway, here it is a solution (when *I guess* how the right data should be):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the field 5 from file1.txt in an array that uses the first two fields as index
for /F "tokens=1,2,5 delims=," %%a in (file1.txt) do set "field5[%%a,%%b]=%%c"

rem Process the file2.txt and insert the field5 of the matching data
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%a in (file2.txt) do echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!field5[%%a,%%b]!
```

This way, if this would be the first file:

```
Abed,Abbas,7,7M5,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
Muzefa,Abbas,7,7M5,8fj/Ma1   Mrs C H CLARK
Taiba,Abbas,7,7M5,11ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
```

then this is the output:

```
Abed,Abbas,P,J3XXXXXXXXXXX,7,NULL,abedabbas,****,A,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
Muzefa,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,8,NULL,muzefaabbas,****,A,8fj/Ma1   Mrs C H CLARK
Taiba,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,11,NULL,taibaabbas,****,A,11ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase my solution:

- Store all names in an array from the following file:

  Abed,Abbas,P,J3XXXXXXXXXXX,7,NULL,abedabbas,****,A
  Muzefa,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,8,NULL,muzefaabbas,****,A
  Taiba,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,11,NULL,taibaabbas,****,A
- Search using each name in the array in the file below

  Isher,Dhupar,7,7M5,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
  Saarah,Hassan,7,7M5,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
  Zenzele,Kabara-Clarke,7,7M5,7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE
- And take the last column (e.g. "7ae/Ma1   Mr K F TREASURE") and add it in the first file at the appropriate name:

  Abed,Abbas,P,J3XXXXXXXXXXX,7,NULL,abedabbas,****,A
  Muzefa,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,8,NULL,muzefaabbas,****,A
  Taiba,Abbas,P,A3XXXXXXXXXXX,11,NULL,taibaabbas,****,A